# Ubuntu + Unable to Edit .bashrc file because of ReadOnly

Tags: bash, ubuntu, vi, read-only

I am getting the following warning:

```
Unable to verify SSL certificate for api.heroku.com
To disable SSL verification, run with HEROKU_SSL_VERIFY=disable
```

By searching Google I was able to find a few solutions. One of them says to add `HEROKU_SSL_VERIFY=disable` to `.bashrc`. Unfortunately, I am not able to edit that file.  When I try I get the following error:

```
'readonly' option is set (add ! to override)
```

`!wq is used in place of :wq`, but no response.

Does anybody have any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: chmod 666 ~/.bashrc might help

Comment: I think it's :wq!, not !wq...

Answer (score 2):

This is a vim issue, not a file permission issue. If you did not have read permission on the file, you'd see a "Permission denied" error.

Do you invoke vi/vim with the `-R` option? Are you calling `view` instead of `vi` or `vim`? Do you have `set readonly` in your .vimrc or in a file in ~/.vim/ftplugin?

In vim you can enter `:set noreadonly` to unset the readonly flag.

Comment: :set noreadonly solved the problem for me. I wasn't aware of that flag. I was able to modify .bashrc before, so how could it have been set by accident?

Comment: Consider the questions I pose in my answer. Do any apply?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't have the write permissions for the `.bashrc` file. That sounds weird because the file `.bashrc` under your home directory should be owned by you. Try this command before you edit the file:

```
chmod +w ~/.bash
```

Comment: Not a file permission problem: the error message is from vi/vim

Answer (score -1):

root@dfyhs5l1:~/cuda/ex/hello# chmod +w ~/.bashrc
chmod: changing permissions of `/home/jalal/.bashrc': Operation not permitted

Comment: What is the relation to the question?